# ASP.NET MVC 3 jQuery client validation - disable for specific button (Ajax form)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

How can I disable validation for one button inside the Ajax begin form?

Using jQuery validation I tried many ways from Google, but none of them worked (`class="cancel"`, disableValidation attribute, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other ways, but one for sure way is to remove all the validation rules if using unobtrusive validation via:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#frmMyName').validate().cancelSubmit=true;
```

Comment: But this removes all the client validation... Right?