# asp.net mvc3 clientside validation disable for button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to save data when a SAVE button is clicked but it needs to ignore validation on the client side and simply post all results. When the FINISH button is clicked, it needs to run through the complete validation for all the controls.
How do you selectively disable clientside validation for asp.net mvc3?

Comment: What are you using for client side validation currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my other post here assuming jquery validation
[ASP.NET MVC 3 jQuery client validation - disable for specific button (Ajax form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240898/asp-net-mvc-3-jquery-client-validation-disable-for-specific-button-ajax-form)

If you aren't using jquery validation for MVC but MS MVC validation then I think the CSS class just needs to be 'cancel'

Comment: If I remove the rules will this affect the button that needs to perform validation?

Answer (score 0):

```
(input id="MyElement" type="submit" value="Save"/)
(script type="text/javascript")
document.getElementById("MyElement").disableValidation=true;

or
>script type="text/javascript">
$("#MyElement").disableValidation=true;
(/script)
```